# Import {} from location is not found in VS Code using TypeScript and Angular 2

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular, typescript1.5

I am trying out the new Angular 2 Forms. My import statements are as follows:

```
import {bootstrap, onChange, NgIf, Component, Directive, View, Ancestor} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {formDirectives, NgControl, Validators, NgForm} from 'angular2/forms';

import {RegExpWrapper, print, isPresent} from 'angular2/src/facade/lang';

import {reflector} from 'angular2/src/reflection/reflection';
import {ReflectionCapabilities} from 'angular2/src/reflection/reflection_capabilities';
```

The 'angular2/angular2' resolves fine, but none of the other "`from`" locations resolve. The error is:

> Cannot find module 'angular2/forms'.

All of these components are currently in my `node_modules` directory. If I put in the full path:

```
import {formDirectives, ControlDirective, Validators, TemplateDrivenFormDirective} from 'C:/Users/Deb/node_modules/angular2/forms';
```

then it works. However, I should not need to use the full path. Am I missing something when I set up the tsconfig or is there something else wrong?

Comment: What kind of module loader are you using? System.js, Webpack, etc. ? The short path to the modules can be set there.

Comment: If it helps, here are some working angular2 boilerplates: http://www.tryangular2.com/category/Boilerplate

Comment: I'm using the new Visual Studio Code editor so assumed it was a setting there somewhere?

Comment: @DeborahK what you are missing is a `.d.ts` file for angular2 forms, when I was playing with it I created a shim of what I needed basically making all the things you need to import be of type `any` and you should be fine (once you reference it of course)

Comment: OK. I added the forms.d.ts file and set a reference path defining its location. Still getting the same issue: "can't find external module angular2/forms"

Comment: I'm not very familiar with VS, but perhaps this [Visual Studio with Angular2 tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/03/12/a-preview-of-angular-2-and-typescript-in-visual-studio.aspx) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that the example application did not match with the version of Angular 2 currently available for download.

If anyone is interested, I now have a working example of Angular2 forms with TypeScript and Visual Studio Code here:

https://github.com/DeborahK/AngularU2015-Angular2Forms

Hope this helps anyone else standing on the "bleeding edge".

Comment: Hi. I took a look at your sample. This might have changed again as I don't see the ng-control directive anymore.